# How to subtract two columns of pyspark dataframe and also divide?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have dataframe like this..

dd1 : -

```
    A    B   
   2112  2637
   1293  2251
   1779  2435
   935   2473
```

I want to substract col B from col A and divide that ans by col A.
Like this

```
    A    B       Result 
   2112  2637    -0.24
   1293  2251    -0.74
   1779  2435    -0.36
   935   2473   -1.64
```

Like (2112-2637)/2112 = -0.24

If it is not possible directly then 1st we can perform substract operation and store it new col then divide that col and  store  in another col.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

General idea is like following:

```
dd1['Result'] = ( dd1['A'] - dd1['B'] ) / dd1['A']
```

In case of Pyspark, it would look something like:

```
dd1 = dd1.withColumn('Result', ( dd1['A'] - dd1['B'] ) / dd1['A'] )
```

Comment: How does it work for subtracting two [string columns within a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69540138/10452700) in PySpark?